# Viable JavaScript Variable Names

Tags: javascript, variables

This is a two part question: General, and Specific.

**For the general:** I often find myself wondering what constitutes a viable variable name in JavaScript? I know there are certain 'words' that can *not* be used as variables in JavaScript; But I have yet to come across either a list of non-viable variable names, or a rule to apply when creating a variable name. I usually err on the side of caution and use obscure names if I am unsure.

It would be nice to know, with certainty, what can be used as a JavaScript variable, and what can not be used.

Any advice?

**For the specific:** I am wondering if I can use `href` as a variable name in my JavaScript? Is it viable, or is it reserved?

---

Afterthought: Perhaps I can extend this question to encompass JavaScript function names as well. What names are viable, and which are reserved? If the two questions are related, I will edit to ask both.

**Note:** I am not asking which characters can be used in a JavaScript variable; That question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names).

Comment: Functions are first-class values, they can be assigned to variables so...

Comment: ... which is to say, if a name is usable for variables it is usable for functions as well, and vice-versa.

Comment: You are most welcome.  In a certain sense, all Javascript functions are variables and my preferred coding style reflects that: `var myFunction = function() { /* stuff */ }`

Comment: I’ve made a tool for this that checks if a given string is a valid variable name as per ECMAScript 5.1: http://mothereff.in/js-variables It will also warn you if the name you entered is a reserved word in an older ECMAScript version (i.e. if you should avoid it for backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find lists of [reserved words in JavaScript.](http://www.kourbatov.com/faq/reserved.htm)

`href` is certainly fine as a variable name because `href` is an attribute of an `a` tag and in no way conflicts with JavaScript naming.

If you are ever in doubt as to whether or not a variable is already in use you can always open the developer tools (F12 in most browsers), go to the console, and type in the name. In this case you'll get:

```
> href
x ReferenceError: href is not defined
```

Nothing is using it, so it is yours to use without problem.

Just for kicks if you did enter a reserved word it would look like:

```
> finally
x SyntaxError: Unexpected token finally
```

Or if it was a native but already taken word it might look like:

```
> Node
function Node() { [native code] }
```

(Node is already defined, and its a native function)

Comment: Thank so much for the prompt answer. What do you think of my "afterthought"? Are there similar rules when defining a function name?

Comment: I have edited to show you a bit more about dealing with which functions are already taken (ie Node is already taken)

Comment: is there a way to protect against future reserved words - like of javascript 9.0 makes href a reserved word?

Comment: No, but its extremely rare that such a case occurs. You'll notice that only 30% or so if JavaScript reserved words are actually used at the moment. The rest are for possible future implementations. In other words, the reserved word list is _already_ a "future reserved words list"

Comment: I really want to use "super" as a var >_<

Comment: @Simon Sarris - Excellent answer. And props for the edit. I'm going to use this from now on to be sure of my variable names.

Comment: It’s not really a good idea to rely on a specific implementation when checking if something is or is not a reserved word. Implementations have bugs, and what works in engine A might break in engine B. Best to use http://mothereff.in/js-variables and see if it displays a warning for your variable name of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, actually, you can use any kind of name as a variable name.

Instead of referring to the variable by name, refer to it by array index, **since all object properties in JS can be accessed by index*, as well as the fact that global variables are simply properties of the `window` object.**

**a string index can contain literally any kind of character sequence*

So the question in turn might be more on the lines of "should I use reserved words as variable names?"
Common sense would say you shouldn't, except when such a name is actually related to the construct and you can't find a suitable replacement.

```
window['function'] = 2;
window['if'] = 4;
window['var'] = 8;
alert(window['function'] + window['if'] + window['var']);
```

---

### **Warning!**

**Reserved words** are different from **native functionality**.
Although in many cases you can use names used as reserved keywords as variables, native functionality can actually be overwritten.
For instance Mr Sarris above mentioned `Node`, (which is a native function not a reserved keyword), you can actually overwrite it by doing `window['Node'] = myNewThing;`. This has been used in some cases to achieve "wrapper" or "hotfix" functionality, but it is not guaranteed to work in a cross-browser manner (eg; MSIE's console object).

Comment: +1 for the warning paragraph. That's an important difference.

Answer (score 1):

[rules](http://www.google.be/search?source=ig&hl=nl&rlz=1G1GGLQ_NLBE272&q=javascript%20variable%20names&oq=javascript%20variable%20names&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=143l6601l0l6794l25l24l0l11l11l0l308l2217l2.7.3.1l13l0) for variable declaration (on codelifter)

href is ok to use

Comment: Thanks for this more extensive list of JavaScript variable rules. I will use this in combination with Simon Sarris' link as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Every programming language has a list of *reserved words*.

These reserved words consist of the parts that constitute that programming language.

For JavaScript, things like `for` or `function` or `if` are reserved words, since these have special meaning in the language *itself*. As a rule of thumb you cannot re-use words as *identifiers* (names) that already have a meaning in that particular language.

The official language specification is a good place to look that up. For JavaScript see the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 7.6.1 (section 7.6. clarifies the other rules that apply to identifier naming).

Your question whether `href` is okay to use in JS is easily answered by looking there.